# ElasticSearch - Export huge indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I need to export indices from an ElasticSearch v2.1 to an ElasticSearch 6.4.
Additionally I need to do a few mutate/rename operations on the docs.

I tried it with log-stash and the elasticsearch input and output plugin. This works, but ... My indices are quite big ~ 50 GB and ~ 200m docs (and have more than 200 indices). So it does take a very long time to export the data (in my case probably around 3 months) Is there a better way to export such a big load of data from an ElasticSearch?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is your end goal to move your data from v2.1 to 6.4 cluster ? If yes, snapshot and restore is what you need. However, please note a snapshot of indices created on 2.x can only be restored on 5.x. So you would need to restore it to a temp 5.x cluster then snapshot indices again and restore them on your 6.4 cluster. Once all your data is in 6.4 - for mutate/ rename operations I would recommend looking at Ingest Node where you can create a pipeline and re-index your data in place